# Bidirectional Communication between two devices using Websockets

Tags: c++, websocket, communication, bidirectional

Can i achieve a real bidirectional communication between a (c++) device in the local network behind a `NAT` and a device (PC) in the internet (not behind a `NAT`) using `websockets`. The begin of communication should be triggered by the network device.

kind regards

Comment: What kind of answer to you expect beyond "Yes"?

Comment: i would like to know if NAT can be a problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets will behave exactly like any other sockets in this regard. If the initiator is behind a NAT device and the recipient is not then it should work (subject to any special policy of the NAT device). If the target is behind a NAT it will not work without some sort of port forwarding setup.